# Modify bundle configuration from another bundle

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I was wondering whether there's a possible to modify a bundles configuration from another bundle. Let's say, for example, I'm using the FOSUserBundle with the following configuration:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

And now, I want to change the user class when loading a specific extension (the `AcmeFoobarExtension`). Is it possible to change the configuration when loading
the `AcmeFoobarExtension`? For example:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\FoobarBundle\DependencyInjection;

// use statements for dependency injection

class FoobarExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->setConfiguration(
            'fos_user.user_class',
            'Acme\FoobarBundle\Entity\User'
        );
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible? Or defeats it the purpose of dependency injection?

EDIT: Apparently there's a [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4652) for Symfony 2.2 which addresses this idea/issue.

EDIT 2: This is now available in Symfony 2.2 (with an [article in the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be noted that this is now an official feature of Symfony:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html

A bundle can prepend configuration values to the global config parameters. To do that, the bundle extension must implement `PrependExtensionInterface`. The `prepend()` method can then add global configuration values.

Note, however, that the values may be overwritten by other bundles and in the config file itself.

Answer (score 2):

After asking the same question on the Symfony user mailing list ([here's the question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/dLaNsgU2fiA)), I've found out that there's an open [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5566) for this idea.

It is for version 2.2 and not yet merged into master, but the last activity is from 3 days ago, so let's hope for the best!