# How to configure a bundle from another bundle in Symfony 3.4?

Tags: configuration, bundle, symfony-3.4

I have a bundle in Symfony. I'd like to make this bundle change the configuration of other bundles. For example I'd like to set Doctrine's default naming strategy or make custom monolog logger configurations used by my bundle. The point is that when I require my bundle into a project I don't want to make these configurations in the app/config.yml, because my bundle will allways use these specific configurations.

Comment: @P. R. Ribeiro thank you for the tip I go even further. What if I want to configure another bundle by parameters in my bundle? So in the prepend() I'd like to set the value of doctrine.orm.naming_strategy to "%my_custom_naming_strategy.class%". This parameter is declared in the bundle itself (../Resources/config/parameters.yml)
The parameters are loaded into the Container in the in the load() or loadInternals() method of the extension which is called AFTER the prepend() method. So in the prepend the Container has no knowledge of my parameters yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify bundle configuration from another bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114932/modify-bundle-configuration-from-another-bundle)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `PrependExtensionInterface` as explained in the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html .